# React Native IOS- Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, flipper

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32539

System:
OS: macOS 11.6
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 145.58 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 17.0.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.17 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 8.1.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
Watchman: 2021.10.18.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 15.0, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000
Xcode: 13.0/13A233 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: Not Found
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.66.1 => 0.66.1
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found

Comment: Please do not repost github issues. Instead, ask a question, share details, and add a [mcve]. Rather than expecting us to follow a github link which could break for future users.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.